# Meteor Accounts without Passwords

Tags: javascript, meteor, user-accounts, meteor-accounts

I'd like to create an account system in Meteor that users cannot create their own accounts, and have no passwords. Essentially the user would be able to login by being given a user account name (in my case a string of integers). I tried using the accounts-pasword module and modifying it, but it doesn't seem obvious to me how I'd do that.

For now, I have a meteor method `createPlayer`:

```
createPlayer: function() {
    var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000).toString();
    Accounts.createUser({ username: id, password: "test" });
    return id;
}
```

and I call this when the server is restarting:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
        Meteor.call("createPlayer");
    }
```

The disadvantage here is (1) there is still a password field that a user has to enter in the default password "test" into, and (2) there is still a button for the user to create a new account, other than the ones I've created already.

Edit: The solution must enable me to publish only that data relevant to the logged-in user. For example, with account-passwords I can use this.userId in publish to always have an up-to-date list of tasks:

```
Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
        var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
        if (user && user.admin) {
            return Tasks.find({});
        }
        return Tasks.find({ user: this.userId });
    });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use password, then you don't need `accounts-password` or any package, just create a collection and insert users into that collection. If you use `simple-schema` then you can define a schema for your collection

```
Users = new Mongo.Collection('userInfo'); //I am using userInfo because, users is used by accounts package

Users_Schema = new SimpleSchema({   
    username: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        optional: false 
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        optional: false
    },
    //.. other details that you need.
});

Users.attachSchema(Users_Schema);
```

Then instead of `Accounts.createUser`, you can insert a new user, you can check if `username` already exists and throw an error accordingly.

```
Users.insert({
    username: "someUniqueUsername",
    firstName: "userFirstName",
    lastName: "userLastName",
    age: 20
});
```

Add [`deny`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deny) rules to this `Users` collection, so that people cannot add or remove users directly from client-side.

```
Users.deny({
    insert: function () {
        return true;
    },
    update: function () {
        return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Update**

As far as I know, you can't achieve login without password using `accounts` package. To clarify your 2nd point in the comment, see the following.

For login form HTML, create a input field for username and a login button,

```
<template name="loginForm">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" /><br/>
    <input id="btnLogin" type="button" value="Login" />
</template>
```

In login JS, write event listener for login button. When login button is pressed, get `userId` and call a server method that checks if the user is available or not. If the result is true, then there is a user in DB, so set a session variable.

```
Template.loginForm.events({
    'click #btnLogin': function (ev, template) {
        var userId = template.$('#username').val();
        //validate if userId is non-empty and valid userId before calling meteor method.
        Meteor.call('loginUser', userId, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                Session.set('userId', null);
                alert("There is an error while logging in.");
            } else {
                if (result === true) {
                    Session.set('userId', userId);
                    Router.go('someRouteAfterLogin'); //redirect to a different page.
                } else {
                    Session.set('userId', null);
                    alert("There is no such user.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

In some other template, where `user` is already logged in, get the

```
Template.someTemplateAfterLogin.onCreated(function () {
    //Actually, this can go inside your Router's current route's data and waitOn but for demonstration purpose
    var userId = Session.get("userId");
    if (userId) {
        this.subscribe('userInfo', userId);
    } else {
         Router.go('login'); //or whatever name you specified for login
    }
});
```

On server side,

```
Meteor.methods({
    'loginUser': function (userId) {
        if (typeof userId == "string") {
            var user = Users.findOne({ username: userId });
            return user ? true : false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

Meteor.publish('userInfo', function (userId) {
    if (typeof userId == "string") {
        return Users.find({ username: userId }); //use second parameter to restrict the fields that you want to publish with something like this return Users.find({ username: userId }, { fields: { username: 1, firstName: 1 } });
    }
    return null;
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't give me the login functionality of Meteor. Also, this way publish won't have access to the user id, so if I want to persist collections from the server to the client, I'd have to persist everything, which is insecure.

Comment: @AMWJ For your first point "This wouldn't give me the login functionality of Meteor", I don't think what you want is a standard login functionality. For your second point "I'd have to persist everything", do you mean publishing? If you are talking about publishing, then you can actually publish only the fields and data you want.

Comment: @AMWJ Basically, you need to add a form yourself and when user clicks the login button, you need to call a meteor method with the `userId`, which will check for `user`'s availability **on the server** and return true, if there is no user then return false.

Comment: And when user logs in, you will publish other information like `firstName` and `lastName` to that client, which is secure.

Comment: (1) I do want the login form and functionality that comes with Meteor, if possible. (2) There is no way that I'm aware of to publish only the logged-in user's firstName and lastName in this solution. How would publish() access the logged-in userId to filter on?

Comment: @AMWJ Updated the answer to clarify your 2nd question. For first question, I don't think it is possible using accounts package to login without password.